# How to install mesa 17.3.1 on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: opengl, mesa

So I'm using Godot game engine on Ubuntu, but I'm having a problem with OpenGL, google led me to this issue:

https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/8700

which confirmed that it's a driver issue and is fixed in mesa 17.3.1.

But I haven't figure out how to install it, I tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
```

then

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

but now I'm only getting

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.2.4
```

I've compiled 17.3.1 from source, but I didn't figure how to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PPA you've added](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/ubuntu/updates) has this in its description:

> This PPA is for stable upstream releases of X.org components. If you're looking for something even more bleeding-edge, please see the xorg-edgers PPA.

...and indeed [xorg-edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) contains mesa 17.3.1 for 16.04.

You can add it with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`.